# How to fix problems with Watir and Watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

If I load Watir using:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'https://www.google.com/'
```

I got these errors:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.9/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/html_elements.rb:17:
warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.9/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/html_elements.rb:137:
warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.9/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/html_elements.rb:138:
warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
```

and a lot more lines...

```
alias_method: undefined method col_span` for class `Watir::TableCell (NameError)
```

And if I use:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
```

I manage to use the gem, but I get this warning:

```
in 'require': require "watir-webdriver" is deprecated. Please, use
require "watir".
```

I don't know if future use of watir-webdriver will cause me problems since is deprecated.

Comment: What version of Watir do you have installed? The current version is 6.15.5. Given that the errors suggest Watir-Webdriver is being pulled in, it sounds like an older version.

Comment: Uninstall watir-webdriver first and then install watir, it would work.